# Load child element only when it required

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8, viewchild

This is my child component

child html 
//add-child.component.html

```
 <div class="content">
        <h6 class="title" translate>
            <span *ngIf="addTitle" translate>Add</span>
            <span *ngIf="editTitle" translate>Edit</span>
        </h6>
        <div class="row">
       <form [formGroup]="administrationForm">
             <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
             formControlName="adminId"
         </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

child component...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-hospital',
  templateUrl: './add-child.component.html'
})
export class AddChildComponent implements OnInit {

 addTitle = true;
 editTitle = false;

}
```

Parent component.html

```
<button (click)="enableChild()"></button>
<app-add-child #newChild></app-add-child>
```

Parent component

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-hospitals',
      templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
    })
    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild(AddChildComponent , { static: true }) newChild: AddChildComponent ;
      @ViewChild(AddChildComponent , { static: true }) set Content(newChildRef) {
        this.newChild = newChildRef;
      }
    constructor(){}

     enableChild() {
      //  this.add = true;
        this.newChild.addTitle = false;
        this.newChild.editTitle = true;
        this.loadById(event);
      }

  loadById() {
//server call
    this.hospitalService.getById().subscribe(response => {
      this.newChild.administrationForm.patchValue({
          adminId: result["adminId"]
    })
   }
}
```

While loading parent, it loads child. It causes a lot of empty space at the end of parents page. I need to load child DOM only when Enable child method is called. I tried adding ngIf in parent on loading the child, but it causes initialization problem , need to use certain child value.

How can I load child when only it required.(ngIf not working as I need child reference when enabled)

Comment: please show the place where `loadHospitalById()` get called. show implementation of `loadById` method. show any other places that use `this.newChild`. better yet, post the whole template and component code for both parent and child, because I suspect that this is a [xy question](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see from your code, you want to pass state from parent to child and doing it in a very tortuous way. All you need is simple [property-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property).

I would start by changing child component as follows;

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-hospital',
  templateUrl: './add-child.component.html'
})
export class AddChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input addTitle = true;
  @Input editTitle = false;
}
```

then get rid of tortuous view queries on parent component;

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hospitals',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  enableChild = false;
  addTitle: boolean;
  editTitle: boolean;

  constructor(){}

  enableChild() {
    this.enableChild = true;
    this.addTitle = false;
    this.editTitle = true;
  }
}
```

and finally;

```html
<button (click)="enableChild()"></button>
<app-add-child *ngIf="enableChild" [addTitle]="addTitle" [editTitle]="editTitle"></app-add-child>
```

Comment: No there are other functionalities I just posted the two values , since the code is too long. This is not what I required. I need to add the child on demand.

Comment: it would be better to see relevant code because the portion you posted doesn't indicate adding child on demand. also, can more than one child be added? please elaborate more on your use case.

Answer (score -1):

you could use `*ngIf` attribute, inside `app-add-child` component, so the component lives but all it's entries are removed

```
//app-data-child-content
<div class="content" *ngIf="show">
    <h6 class="title" translate>
        <span *ngIf="addTitle" translate>Add</span>
        <span *ngIf="editTitle" translate>Edit</span>
    </h6>
    <div class="row">
       <!-- form -->
    </div>
</div>
...
class ChildAddComponent{
   @Input()
   show=false;
}

///parent-component
<button (click)="enableChild()"></button>
<app-add-child [show]="showChild" #newChild></app-add-child>
...
class ParentComponent{
    showChild=false;

    enableChild() {
    this.showChild=true;
    this.enableChild = true;
    this.addTitle = false;
    this.editTitle = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: *ngIf is used , then this.enableChild = true;
    this.addTitle = false; will not work. I already mentioned this in th question ngIF solution will not work here like this.

Comment: you mentioned, that you need a reference for the child component and this way you will hold it but avoid extra DOM of the child component